# how to decode json sting including array and object in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, json, object

I want to decode json string including array and object in PHP. When i decoded with

---

```
$array = json_decode($json, true); 
print_r($array);
```

---

it return NULL. Let me know, the way to decode json in PHP. This is my json string.

---

```
{
    success: 1,
    message: "Successful!",
    save_date: "2013-09-11 04:09:26",
    test: [
        {
        test_id: "1",
        test_date: "2013-09-12",
        test_name: "Test 1"
        },
        {
        test_id: "2",
        test_date: "2013-09-11",
        test_name: "Test 2"
        }
    ]
}
```

---

Comment: you have problems with your json object

Answer (score 0):

That's not a valid JSON object. JSON objects must enclose all property names in double quotes:

```
{ "success": 1, "message": "Successful!" }
```

PHP provides the handy [`json_last_error_msg`](http://php.net/json_last_error_msg) function to tell you that.

There's also the online tool [JSONLint](http://jsonlint.com/) to validate JSON strings.

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON is invalid, the property names need to be in quotes too.

Like this:

```
{
    "success": 1,
    "message": "Successful!",
    "save_date": "2013-09-11 04:09:26",
    "test": []
}
```

Hint: use [JSONLint](http://jsonlint.com/) to validate your JSON.

Answer (score 0):

your json string should be like the following :

```
$sJson = '{"success": 1,"message": "Successful!","save_date": "2013-09-11 04:09:26",
           "test": [    {"test_id": "1","test_date": "2013-09-12","test_name": "Test 1"},
                {"test_id": "2","test_date": "2013-09-11","test_name": "Test 2"}]}';
```

Answer (score -1):

Use this

```
   $result=(array)json_decode('your json string');
```

I think it's working for you

Comment: The OP's JSON string is invalid. There's no need to add a cast if the string is valid.